# file manager : problem to open files in subfolders under the first folder Start

Tags: php

I'm trying to code a file manager. So i can open the files in all folders. It works for the first folder "Start" but not for the subfolders in Start. When i click on the files which are in the subfolders under Start, it automaticcally goes back to Start.

Can someone help me understand why ?

This is the breadcrumbs :

```
  $start ="Start";
  if(!is_dir($start)){
    mkdir($start);
  }

  if(!isset($_POST['cwd'])){
      $directory = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $start;
  }else {
    $directory = $_POST['cwd'];
  }

  $contentDirectory = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $directory);
  $path = "";

  echo "<form method='post' id='ch_cwd'> </form>";
              foreach($contentDirectory as $content){
                $path .= $content . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                if(strstr($path,$start)){
                    echo "<button type='submit' name='cwd' form='ch_cwd' value='" . substr($path, 0, -1) . "' class='breadcrumb-item'> " . $content . "</button>";
                }
              }
```

And the files are buttons :

```
  $dir = scandir($directory);
        //print_r($dir);
        foreach( $dir as $item){
          if($item !== "." && $item !== ".."){

            if($item[0] === "."){
              echo "";
            }
            elseif(is_dir($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item)){
              echo "<button type='submit' name='cwd' form='ch_cwd' value='" . $directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item . "' class='d-inline-block pr-4'> " . "<i class='fas fa-folder-open fa-4x pt-2 pb-2 pr-2 text-primary'></i>". $item . "</button>";
            }
            else{
              echo "<button type='submit' name='file' form='ch_cwd' value='" . $directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item  . "' class='d-inline-block pr-4'> " . "<i class='fas fa-file fa-4x pt-2 pb-2 pr-2 text-primary'></i>". $item . "</button>";
              $filename = $directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item;
              if (file_exists($filename) >0 && isset($_POST['file']) ){
                $ressource = fopen($filename, 'rb');
                echo fread($ressource, filesize($filename));
              }
            }

          }
        }
```

Do you have any advice ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In linux:

you need to change ownership of sub folders to `www-data`
in terminal

```
chown -R www-data mainfolder
```

replace mainfolder with your main folder name

and then

```
chmod -R 775 mainfolder
```

In windows:

right-click on main folder > properties > security
and give read/write permissions to users

Comment: hey, no that's not the problem, the permissions are good